# qt5: why 2 processes and memory usage?

Tags: c++, linux, qt5

I uses 64 linux with fresh install of qt 5.1.0.

I take example application qtbase/examples/widgets/widgets/lineedits and run, let's call it qt5_lineedit,
also I take the similar app from qt4 sources build it with qt4 library and run.

And in htop I see that, there are two qt5_lineedit (I run only one, so it used 2 threads) and memory usage:
VIRT  223M RES 18268.

While for qt4_lineedit exists only one process and it eats:
VIRT 126M RES 15848.

So,

1. Why qt5 uses two threads by default?
2. Why so much diffrence in virtual memory size?

Update.

In spite of qt5_lineedit uses 2 pids, they are not processes, but threads.
So info about qt4_lineedit looks like:

```
VmPeak:   130936 kB
VmSize:   130932 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     17140 kB
VmRSS:     17140 kB
VmData:     4524 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:        28 kB
VmLib:     48232 kB
VmPTE:       220 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        1
```

The info about qt5_lineedit looks like:

```
VmPeak:   278020 kB
VmSize:   228584 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     18268 kB
VmRSS:     18268 kB
VmData:    77468 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:        28 kB
VmLib:     50056 kB
VmPTE:       288 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        2
```

Comment: What do you mean with "1)Why qt5 fork?"?

Comment: lineedit is simple example application provided by qt. it NOT uses qprocess and similar things. But instead of one qt5_lineedit I see two qt5_lineedit processes, obviously this is mean that somewhere in qt5 fork was called. But for what reason?

Comment: Are you sure they are two separate processes and not two threads of the same process?

Comment: Yes you right, I thought since time when pthreads has ntpl inside, different PID means different process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second thread (not process) comes from the **XCB QPA plugin**, which [spawns a thread to poll for XCB events](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/blobs/stable/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbconnection.h#line284). (I don't know if that's for working around XCB bugs, XCB API or what.)

In general, you *can't compare two processes memory usage by looking at VM summaries*. You need to properly analyze the processes' memory maps (`/proc/pid/maps`), and figure out how much memory got allocated, and where, and if it's getting shared amongst other processes or it's real per-process usage. Moreover, if you see a difference in dynamically-allocated memory, you need further analysis about the per-process usage by using a heap profiler (such as valgrind's massif).

Who said that profiling memory usage was an easy task? :)

Comment: Yes, I found in git commit that introduce thread usage into xcb plugin. This is work around for xcb bug.

Answer (score 1):

I found something about multiple threads in a simple application that might be interesting: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/10656

I for myself can think of, that (we may all know) the `QCoreApplication` runs its own event queue. And to accomplish that, it will need an independent thread to not block the mainthread from executing.

On the memory usage i have no specific clue, but maybe it is caused due changes in the way Qt draws its widgets.

soo long zai

Comment: About link it tells about windows specific things, on Linux I suppose no threads that deal with COM+ objects.

Comment: About QCoreApplication and event loop. As you see Qt4 use one thread, and this question about diffrence between Qt4 and Qt5. In other words if in Qt5 we need one more thread to work with events, why in Qt4 you use only one and all works fine.

Comment: @user1034749 on windows if you run a empty console application using qt4.8.3, you will get 2 threads. unfortunately i cannot tell how it looks in linux